# Java LineNumberReader reset to beginning

Tags: java, inputstream, reset

I want to read an `InputStream` in two passes, line by line. I use the following code for the first pass:

```
LineNumberReader reader = new LineNumberReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

String line;
String eventId = null;
Set<Integer> artistIds = new HashSet<Integer>();
while((line = reader.readLine())!=null) {
    // process first pass
}

// how do I reset reader so that I can read from the beginning again?
```

There is a `reset()` method available but it resets to the last `mark` in the file. I don't quite understand what that means. Can I use `mark` and `reset` to achieve the `reset to beginning` behavior? Something like

```
LineNumberReader reader = new LineNumberReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
reader.mark(0); // mark at the 0th position
// process first pass: repeated calls to readline() until EOF

reader.reset(); // reset to 0th position??
// process second pass
```

While testing at my local machine, I was `reader.close()`-ing before the second pass and it worked. However, when I do this in HDFS, `reader.close()` probably closes the HDFS InputStream too and I get a `java.io.IOException: Stream closed` exception.

Comment: `reader.mark(0); // mark at the 0th position` should be: `reader.mark(really_big_number); // set read ahead limit higher than bytes to read`.

Comment: @ebyrob: what are `mark` and `reset` used for? Could you point to an example?

Answer (score 1):

Mark and reset work, but don't call `.mark(0)` that sets the read ahead limit to 0 which means `.reset()` won't work reliably if you read more than 0 bytes.

**EDIT:** `.mark()` marks the current location in the stream.  Unlike C++ where you can `.seek()` the beginning or end of a file and offsets, Java streams only allow you to mark a current location and then go back to it with `.reset()`.  This can go "back to the beginning" but only if it was marked before processing started.

Try this:

```
import java.io.*;

public class StreamTwice
{
   public static void printLines(LineNumberReader r) throws IOException
   {
      String line;
      while( (line = r.readLine()) != null )
         System.out.println(line);
      System.out.println();
   }

   public static void main(String []args) throws Exception
   {
      ByteArrayInputStream s = new ByteArrayInputStream(
         "one\ntwo\nthree".getBytes()
      );
      LineNumberReader r = new LineNumberReader(new InputStreamReader(s));

      r.mark(5000); // more than the number of bytes being read.
                    // this is the read ahead limit.  
      printLines(r);

      r.reset();    // go back to where mark was called.
      printLines(r);
   }
}
```

Try to make sure you don't read more bytes than the read ahead limit you set in `.mark()` before calling `.reset()`.

P.S. - Not all streams (or readers) support `.mark()`, which you can check with `.markSupported()`.

Answer (score 0):

Reset() resets the line reader to the most recent mark (which is the last if you are going sequentially.) What you need to do is manually change the line by calling " reader.SetLineNumber(0); " the parameter indicates the line number that you want to go to.

Comment: Sorry. It does not work. Didn't reset to the beginning.

Comment: What did it do instead?